# Can't access compute instance in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vps

I can't access google cloud compute instance with ssh os login (enabled before), I can't even use console to connect to ssh.

I didn't get any response after hours of trying, my running service is stopped, when checking on info panel my cpu usage is 50%-60% but the network usage is very low.

I tried changing region but same thing happen after 12-24 hours running.

My temporary solution is shutting down the server for couple minutes and start again

You can check my server here
http://35.197.92.158/

Comment: screenshots maybe help
https://prnt.sc/tygyec
https://prnt.sc/tygynr
https://prnt.sc/tygywa

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the disk space of the instance using the serial console port  [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) when you are not able to login using SSH. If the root partition is full then this might happen. Moreover, you can follow the SSH troubleshooting [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh?hl=en) to resolve the issue at your end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check your firewall policy and make sure your ip is the only one alloweds to connect. Once the policy are ok, restart your instance and instantly login via ssh: check system and application log files to find out what's happening.